# How To Create React App Scaffolding CLI/Script

Tags: reactjs, vite

I was wondering how you go about customising a react app creation CLI/script like https://github.com/t3-oss/create-t3-app or CRA/Vite. I would want to create the vite app, with certain libraires added to the package.json and certain folders/files to be created.